# Create a unique string used for saving data

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm building an application for the iphone. I scan the iPod library and bring in all the album art. I need a way of creating a unique string so that when I'm saving the album art to the documents directory, each file has a unique name. Does anyone know to create a unique string? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to be creating a GUID or UUID, which is a 128-bit integer that has a string associated with it.  Check out http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFUUIDRef/Reference/reference.html

Answer (score 14):

I use this code:

```
+ (NSString *)getUniqueFilenameInFolder:(NSString *)folder forFileExtension:(NSString *)fileExtension {
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *existingFiles = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:folder error:nil];
    NSString *uniqueFilename;

    do {
        CFUUIDRef newUniqueId = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
        CFStringRef newUniqueIdString = CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, newUniqueId);

        uniqueFilename = [[folder stringByAppendingPathComponent:(NSString *)newUniqueIdString] stringByAppendingPathExtension:fileExtension];

        CFRelease(newUniqueId);
        CFRelease(newUniqueIdString);
    } while ([existingFiles containsObject:uniqueFilename]);

    return uniqueFilename;
}
```

Maybe it helps someone. :-)

Keep in mind, that this returns the full path of the unique file. You might want to add some small changes to just return the filename. For example if you want to persist it somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the code, but you could generate an MD5 hash code out of the album art.  That would be close to a unique string.  It would be an ugly string though.