# MPMediaItem generating unique filename

Tags: ios, ios5, mpmediaitem

I am importing items from the iPod library and want to generate a unique filename for each MPMediaItem imported. I want the filename to uniquely represent one MPMediaItem so that if the user imports it again I do not have two files that are the same in the local library.

What's the best way of achieving this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a unique string used for saving data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343003/create-a-unique-string-used-for-saving-data)

Comment: @jeffamaphone - not a duplicate, the other question is about creating unique file names, this is about creating filename to represent a media item uniquely. If the media item is imported twice it will have the same filename, a guid does not cut it in this situation

Comment: If a globally unique identifier isn't unique enough, then I don't know what will help. I'm not sure you've phrased your question clearly.

Comment: @jeffamaphone I think it is clear if you take the time to read the whole question. It says "I want the filename to uniquely represent one MPMediaItem so that if the user imports it again I do not have two files that are the same in the local library" - clear as day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly but each MPMediaItem has a unique identifier

[mediaItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID];

this returns an NSNumber that is a longlong. Hope this helps or if I have miss understood let me know.

Comment: and this identifier will be the same if i delete an album and redownload it at a later date?

Comment: The value of the MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID identifier persists across application launches and across syncs that do not change the sync status of the media item. The value is not guaranteed to persist across a sync/unsync/sync cycle.